# JSON data in jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I already have JSON data in this format:

```
{"attributes":{"status":"1","cmd":"check"},"domains":{"domain":{"attributes":{"name":"google.co.ug","avail":"0"}}}}
```

and i am trying to access it like this

```
for (var i=0; i<json.domains.length; i++) {
    for (var b=0;b<json.domains[i].domain.length;b++) {
            //this is the object you are looking for
    }
}
```

I want to get name and avail values only i am however not sure about the for loop structure that i am using

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using loop you can get directly that value like

```
var json = {"attributes": {"status": "1", "cmd": "check"}, "domains": {"domain": {"attributes": {"name": "google.co.ug", "avail": "0"}}}};

name:
json.domains.domain.attributes.name

avail:
json.domains.domain.attributes.avail
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you get your JSON response in string format then first you need to parse it

```js
var jsonObj = {
    "attributes": {
        "status": "1",
        "cmd": "check"
    },
    "domains": {
        "domain": {
            "attributes": {
                "name": "google.co.ug",
                "avail": "0"
            }
        }
    }
};

// only required if your json in string format otherwise ignore
// var result = $.parseJSON(jsonObj);
$.each(jsonObj.domains.domain.attributes, function(k, v) {
    //display the key and value pair
    console.log(k + ' is ' + v);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```